# ". import certs"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl-certificate

I am using facepy for GAE with python

I got a an error and when I track the error, I found

```
from . import certs
```

in utils.py file

What does the dot (.) mean?

certs.py is just in the same folder with utils.py

Answer (score 2):

It is a [relative import](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), which means basically what you say in your last sentence - it is going to look in the current folder relative to the current module to find the module `certs`.

Answer (score 0):

It means import from the same folder.  See if there's an __init__.py file in that folder, if not that might be why it's unhappy.